# Weird error when trying to upgrade to Fedora 24

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

I'm following the instructions posted on Fedora Magazine (https://fedoramagazine.org/upgrading-fedora-23-workstation-to-fedora-24/). I'm getting this message after dnf downloads everything:

```
 Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/fonts/tex-gyre from install of texlive-tex-gyre-ib-svn18651.2.004-25.fc24.1.noarch conflicts with file from package tex-gyre-ib-fonts-2.005-1.fc23.noarch
```

Then when I try to run `dnf system-upgrade reboot`, I get `error: system is not ready for upgrade`.

Any way this could be fixed?

I tried installing texlive, but got the same error.

Comment: do you have some third party repositories?

Comment: @Jakuje yeah, I have quite a few. gyazo and some coprs. why?

Comment: The article clearly says "*If you are having issues upgrading and have third-party repositories installed on your system, you may need to disable these repositories while you are upgrading. For support with repositories not provided by Fedora, please contact the providers of the repositories.*"

Comment: my third party repos were listed at the beginning of the download command, here's the output http://hastebin.com/esaderisal

Comment: It does not mean that it does not conflict with any other package. `texlive-tex-gyre-ib` is not from Fedora repository (`dnf info texlive-tex-gyre-ib`) will tell you where does it come from. Really, disable that repository before update as proposed or uninstall that package.

Comment: From a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361793/subversion-error-while-updating-server) it was proposed erase update and reinstall... If you will not find alternatives...

Comment: @Jakuje I uninstalled `texlive-tex-gyre-ib-fonts` and it works! Thanks, if you could turn that comment into an answer (I believe there's a button for that) I'll mark it as the answer:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `texlive-tex-gyre-ib` is not from Fedora repository.

```
dnf info texlive-tex-gyre-ib`
```

will tell you where does it come from. Really, disable that repository before update as proposed in the documentation or uninstall that conflicting package.